# QSize vs using 2 Int has constants

Tags: c++, qt, constants, qt-creator

I'm doing a project needing 2 constants:

```
Minimum Size of application (Width, Height) 
Initial Size of application (Width, Height)
```

I would like to know which would take less memory cossumption to do:

> 1- One QSize (which the variable would contain the initial width and
>   height and the minimum being scaled of this QSize)
>
> 2- 4 ints (MinH, MinW, IniH, IniW)

Thanks for your suggestions !

Comment: Does it matter? Select, what you like

Comment: How many millions of application sizes do you store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
std::cout << "QSize: " << sizeof(QSize) << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
QSize: 8
```

you do the math.

Comment: Thanks I forgot about sizeof!
It gives 4 for a single int, so it's pretty much the same of doing a QSize, because two ints gives 8.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "the minimum being scaled of this QSize".

QSize is essentially just a struct wrapping 2 ints, so it uses the same amount of memory as 2 ints.

I doubt very much that any platform where you'd need to worry about the memory footprint of 4 integers would have dimensions greater than 64k, so if memory is really an issue you should consider using 4 unsigned shorts instead of 4 ints, which would use half the memory.